# How to get url dynamically in HTML page using DOJO

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

for example, i have 2 url's: which i supposed to enter in some .jsp page, when i enter these url's, browser internally navigate to index.html page(this index.html should not displayed) and should read the url dynamically and should redirect to corresponding .jsp page based on server name.

www.server01/demo/../com

www.server02/demo/../com

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should work, replace values SERVER1 and SERVER2 with the relevant server names

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var hostname = window.location.hostname;     
    if( hostname == "SERVER1" )
    { 
        window.location="SERVER1/page1.jsp";
    }
    else if ( hostname == "SERVER2")
    {
        window.location = "SERVER2/page2.jsp";
    } 
    else {
        alert('Page not found');
    }
    </script>
</head>
```